# Codewars - Swift Solution (Multiply Function)

Tags: swift

```
func multiply(_ a: Double, _ b: Double) -> Double {
    a * b
}
```

What's wrong with this part of code? I am having trouble trying to figure it out.

Comment: The compiler message `error: missing return in a function expected to return 'Double'` should help ...

Comment: Doesn't the compiler already assume that that's what I want returned because it's the only line of code?

Comment: This is literally the first coding challenge on the front page u solve before registration ,Lmao

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** in newer versions of Swift, OP's code works too, since `return` is no longer needed if there is only one expression in the body of a funcion/variable. [Details here.](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/understanding-swift/when-is-the-return-keyword-not-needed-in-a-swift-function)

---

**You are not doing anything with the result.**

`-> Double` indicates that this function should return a `Double`. For that, you should use the `return` keyword:

```
func multiply(_ a: Double, _ b: Double) -> Double {
    return a * b
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
public class Multiply 
{ 
   public double multiply(double a, double b) 
   { return a * b;} 
}


public class Multiply
{
   public static Double multiply(Double a, Double b)
   {
       return a * b;
   }
}
```

Comment: can you explain the code you wrote? also making clear what is the difference from the other solution will add value to your.